# Print files that are not accesible from www-root?

Tags: php, file

I'm storing pdfs in a folder called pdf. This folder is not accesible through `http://domain/pdf/`. (and I don't think it should be)

So I can't do like

```
<a href="http://nameofdomain/pdf/pdf_file1.pdf">pdf file 1</a>
<a href="http://nameofdomain/pdf/pdf_file2.pdf">pdf file 2</a>
<a href="http://nameofdomain/pdf/pdf_file3.pdf">pdf file 3</a>
```

I have an admin-system where I want to print the files (when logged in). How could I print these pdfs to the user? (I want them to show in the browser, but I don't want them public accessible)

Comment: `"I want them to show in the browser, but I don't want them public accessible"` is somewhat of an oxymoron.

Comment: Tokens? ... What have you tried?

Comment: The bet programmer in the world strikes again

Comment: You'll have to use some sort of library to read the PDF files, and convert them to plain-text or HTML.  See [this](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php) link, or [this](http://www.fpdf.org/) PHP class.

Comment: I was not looking for someone to the job for me, just looking for some pointers. I've got an answer already that I'm satisfied with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, you mean these static files should not be accessible to non-logged-in users.

Typically, [`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) is used to transfer files like this from a non-web-accessible location to a browser.

Comment: aha. Thanks! Exactly what I meant!

Comment: ceejayoz was {"which"programmerintheworld}? ;)

Comment: @JanakaRRajapaksha - maybe not one of my brightest moments :-)