# How do I open an pdf from an ajax-call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf

This is my attempt to open a pdf through ajax, but something is obviously incorrect.

(code-snippet)

```
function show_invoice() {
    $data = $this->input->get('info', TRUE);

    $user_id = $data['user_id'];
    if ($user_id != strval(intval($user_id))) {
        throw new exception('no id for user is set for creating pdf');
    }

    //Load pdf into browser
    $filename_pdf = 'pdf/invoice'  . $user_id . '.pdf';                      
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize ( $filename_pdf ) ); 
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream"); 
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($filename_pdf)); 
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    ob_clean();
    flush();

    //Must use readfile because the file isn't 
    //accesible through the browser through for example
    //http://domain/pdf/invoice_21.pdf                                     
    readfile($filename_pdf); 
}
```

js (code-snippet)

```
var info = {};
info.user_id = user_id;

//Send get request to show pdf
var showInvoice = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: {info: info},
    url: CI.base_url + 'member/show_invoice', //CI.base_url is a CodeIgniter constant
    dataType: "json" //WHAT datatype to use here?
});

showInvoice.done(function(data) {  
    //do something      
});
```

I've also tried with stuff as `echo json_encode(readfile($filename_pdf));` (but I didn't believe in it for a moment)

**UPDATE:**

I'm using AJAX because I can't do like `<a href="domain/pdf/invoice_21.pdf">Show invoice</a>` because the file is not accessible directly in the browser.

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious, but why are you using AJAX for this at all? Also, I assume that is pseudo-code?

Comment: @RGraham - because it's not accesible through http://domain/pdf/invoice.pdf - then I would just do <a href="/pdf/invoice{userid}.pdf">Show invoice</a>. Is there a better (another) way of achieving this?

Comment: @RGraham - the code is just an attempt to get the functionality to work. Why do you presume it is is pseudo-code?

Comment: It's invalid syntax, for Javascript at least. Also if the file is not directly accessible in the browser, how would an AJAX request help?

Comment: @RGraham - aha forgive me. the code is in CodeIgniter. Based on answer I've gotten before readfile is used to transfer files from a non-web-accessible location to a browser - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23878632/print-files-that-are-not-accesible-from-www-root.

Comment: That is true. And your function will work on the server-side. But all you have to do is have a link like this: `<a href="/member/show_invoice" download>Show Invoice</a>`. Your server will return it as a PDF and your browser will download it :)

Comment: haha. OF COURSE. Thank you!! Sometimes I just want to kill myself (no, not for real :-)) Put it down as an answer and I will accept.